# Android MapView display empty

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, android-mapview

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.yu.lbs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.yu.lbs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:apiKey=".........."
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

The Activity can be started. But in the MapView there is nothing. The small grid of map can be show, I think that comes with MapView, but no map is loaded. What could be wrong? I am using Google API v3. But this code is from a text book using API v1.

Comment: Did iU Choose "Google API" project Build Target? and add this       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: Yup I have Google APIs [Android 4.3] in my package explorer under my project.

Comment: Have you checked your internet connection speed?

Comment: The speed is fine. I can see maps in Google Maps, but not in my app.

Comment: @PadmaKumar I tried it, but the map still doesnt show..

Comment: how U generated the android:apiKey ?

Comment: @PadmaKumar at Google API Console, I turned on V2 and V3 and got the the key in API Acess under Simple API Acess

Answer (score 62):

The way I got mine resolved, I had to do this:

```
final MapView mapView = (MapView)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.map_fieldLocation);

mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(match.match.LocationLatitude, match.match.LocationLongitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title(match.match.LocationAddress));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 15));
        mapView.onResume();
    }
});
```

The important part that I was missing is that you have to call the `onCreate()` method before you call `getMapAsync()` and once the callback is called, you need to call `onResume()` on the `MapView` object.

That totally solved it for me.

Here's what it would look like in your own class:

```
public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (getView() != null) {

            final MapView mapView = (MapView)getView().findViewById(R.id.mapView);

            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                    LatLng coordinates = new LatLng(match.match.LocationLatitude, match.match.LocationLongitude);
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(coordinates).title(match.match.LocationAddress));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 15));
                    mapView.onResume();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answering this, I didn't call mapView.onResume().

Comment: According to this tutorial: https://inducesmile.com/android/android-mapview-example-tutorial/ the onResume and similar lifecycle calls should be on in the Activity/Fragment lifecycle methods.

Comment: "When using the API in fully interactive mode, users of the MapView class must forward the following activity lifecycle methods to the corresponding methods in the MapView class: onCreate(), onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onStop(), onDestroy(), onSaveInstanceState(), and onLowMemory().  
...
When using the API in lite mode, forwarding lifecycle events is optional. For details, see the lite mode documentation."
from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map

So... my solution is:
mMapView.onCreate(Bundle.EMPTY);
mMapView.onResume();

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are making a mess from the version of Google Maps you are trying to implement.
From the code that is used by you it's seems that you are trying to use Google Maps API V1.

The problem with that is that you can't produce now days a new API key for Google Map API V1, this version is deprecated and Google doesn't provide new keys for it.

from the comments it's looks that in the API Console you didn't activated the right API.
Take a look at this blog post to get an Idea of how to produce an API Key for **Google Map API V2 for Android**:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Next, go over the following guide to implement this version in you application:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

Answer (score 0):

Use Map API V2 for google map in android. Visit this [link](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/gps-and-google-map-in-android-applications-series/) may be helps you.

It is better than old version and easier too.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) (as of today) you need to forward lifecycle callbacks to the MapView. 
A cleaner way to do this is to use [LifecycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver).
This works when the map is placed in an activity or fragment.

You don't get `onLowMemory()` or `onSaveInstanceState()` but you could still forward those to the MapView.

Here's a Kotlin example.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView

class MyMapView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : MapView(context, attrs, defStyle), LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        if(context is LifecycleOwner) {
            context.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
        }
    }

    //Your code here

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
    fun create() {
        onCreate(null)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    fun start() {
        onStart()
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun resume() {
        onResume()
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
    fun pause() {
        onPause()
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    fun stop() {
        onStop()
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun destroy() {
        onDestroy()
    }
}
```