# How to use map in every item of my recycler view

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-recyclerview

I'm using recyclerview for my android application which each item contains a map.

**my question** is how to implement this ?

I tried two ways to implement this(fragment and mapview). The first way was using fragment in XML file and SupportMapFragment in my java class. By this method of implementation I got this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
```

But when I used MapView I got a white view and nothing else :|

I implemented fragment this like

HERE IS XML FILE

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/all_order_each_item_map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"
            tools:context=".AllOrdersActivity"/>
```

HERE IS HOW I INITIALIZE MAP IN MY JAVA CLASS

```
 mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.all_order_each_item_map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Then I used mapView as my second way this like
HERE IS XML FILE

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/all_order_each_item_map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_4sdp"/>
```

CODE BELOW SHOWS HOW I INITIALIZE MAPVIEW IN MY JAVA CLASS

```
mapFragment = viewHolder.root_view.findViewById(R.id.all_order_each_item_map);
```

I used this library (https://github.com/lisawray/groupie) as my recyclerview adapter

In advance, I apologize for language mistakes and any other problems.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find answer by getting help from this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/30484062/10401375 and editing some part of my code